# How do I compare the value of select dropdown option with a div class to toggle this for visibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, toggle

I have a dropdown say list of countries, and below that I have a div's with classes say map-uk, map-fr, map-es. Now onchange of the dropdown I want to see that which country is selected and based on that show that particular map , which is in a div that has class equal to the value of dropdown.

I am trying something like below:

```
    $(function() {
    $("select").onchange(function() {
    if($(this).val() == //I need to compare the class of div that has map)
    {
   //show that map
//hide others
    }
    })
    })
```

is there any better option to do this. I dont want to do like

```
$(function() {
    $("select").onchange(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "uk")
    {
    $(.map_uk).show();
    $(.map_fr,.map_es).hide()
    }

if($(this).val() == "fr")
    {
    $(.map_fr).show();
    $(.map_uk,.map_es).hide()
    }
blah blah blah
    })
    })
```

Comment: Not sure you tested your current approach, but 1) it's `.change`, and 2) selectors are strings.

Comment: I just put my approach. I didnt exactly copy paste my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create general class and specific class for your element like `class="map map_uk"` or `class="map map_es"`. So, you can do this

```
$(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
       $('.map').hide();
       $('.map_'+$(this).val()).show();        
    });
    $("select").change();
});
```

Comment: It works only after I click one of the drop down options. when I refresh the page, I see all the three divs

Comment: @Mike yes of course. Next, you need to fire `$("select").change()` on load event.

Comment: Thanks but just wondering how did that help. do you want to share that info with me.

Comment: @Mike The function will be called if just selected index of dropdown is changed. On initial state, like refresh, the function will not be called. So, all `div`s on the visible state. So, just call the function to read selected index of dropbox and hide `div`s

Comment: thanks, but i am still confused what this does alfter load $("select").change();

Comment: @Mike `.change(function` is mean assigning function to change event and `.change()` is mean calling that function programmatically without change event.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
// #mapsHolder - div that contains all .map_* divs
$("select").onchange(function() {
    // hide all maps
    $('#mapsHolder > div').hide();
    // find a map with class ('.map_' + current value) which will turn into 'map_uk' etc
    $('#mapsHolder .map_' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the value and the class match you could do something like

```
$('.map_' + $(this).val())
```

to select the corresponding element.